# Add "nan" to numpy histogram python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

I am using random library to generate 5000 data points from a Gaussian distribution and then using the data to compute histogram with 10 bins, see code below.

```
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
arrHist = np.histogram(s, 10)
print(arrHist)
```

Output is:

```
(array([   9,   48,  282,  800, 1436, 1424,  742,  216,   40,    3]), 
 array([1.52017489, 1.61690575, 1.71363661, 1.81036747, 1.90709834,
       2.0038292 , 2.10056006, 2.19729092, 2.29402179, 2.39075265,
       2.48748351]))
```

As you can see there are different array lengths and therefore I want to add `np.nan` to the shorter array, so that array lengths are the same. I know it is possible to use `np.append` to append values to the end of an array, but how can I do it when there are two arrays in `arrHist`?

I am new with python, therefore is any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need them to be the same length? The first array of your output is the histogram values and second array are the bin edges. The second array will always be ONE element longer than the first array.

Comment: @not_speshal it is an assignment that says that I have to deal with the counts and bin arrays have different lengths. Therefore I think I have to add some value, to get the array lengths to be the same, but maybe that the wrong way to deal with it. How would you normally deal with that?

Comment: I have no idea what your assignment is so I can't help.

Comment: my suggestion is, instead of adding `None` to `hist`, you should better calculate the "mean" of bin edges, take it as a representative value for that bin. by this way, you will get `n` representative values for `n+1` edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result=[]
max_len=max([len(x) for x in arrHist])
for x in arrHist:
    if len(x)!=max_len:
        x=x.astype('float')
        x=np.pad(x, (0,max_len-len(x)), 'constant', constant_values=(np.nan, ))
    result.append(x)
```